# Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException when debugging WinUI 3 App in VSCode

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, .net-core, winui-3

I've started with a very basic WinUI 3 project whose `.xaml` and `.cs` files are identical to the ones produced by the Blank WinUI 3 template in Visual Studio. But instead of Visual Studio, I'm using Visual Studio Code to debug.

Even though the app launches perfectly well when run with the dotnet command-line interface ( `dotnet run --project MyApp\MyApp.csproj` ), in VS Code it throws a `Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException` in `MainWindow.xaml.cs` on the line `this.InitializeComponent()`.

What is going on? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When used as a debugger, Visual Studio Code (or its OmniSharp C# extension) produces a `launch.json` file (in its hidden `.vscode` directory) that defines launch configurations.

By default, it generates configurations named `.NET Core Launch (console)` and `.NET Core Attach`.

I was trying to debug with the `.NET Core Launch (console)` configuration. This is not such a bad choice, except that it attempts to run the `.dll` file generated by the build, rather than its `.exe`.

To resolve this, in `launch.json`, I copied the `.NET Core Launch (console)` object and gave the copy a new name - `.NET Core Launch (desktop)`. I changed the file referenced by its `program` property from my app's `.dll` to my app's `.exe`.

Then, on VS Code's *RUN AND DEBUG* menu, I selected the new `.NET Core Launch (desktop)` and clicked the green arrow to run.

It now launches with no errors.